# Capture Ctlr+Z in mfc

Tags: mfc, undo-redo

I am trying to cut/copy/paste in my application and for that I need to capture Ctrl+Z etc.
I have written following code in my    OnKeyDown() event handler:

```
if(GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0)
{

    WPARAM wparam = (WPARAM(nChar));

    switch(wparam)
    {
    case 'z':
        //display message box
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

But my problem is that the multiple key strokes never get captured. I can capture single button press for Ctrl key or any other key for that matter.But if I press Ctrl+Z on my keyboard, only ctrl is captured and z is ignored. Could somebody pls suggest a better way to handle multiple key strokes?

Comment: Are you sure that Ctrl+Z isn't in the accelerator list, so it might get captured in the PreTranlsateMessage Handler

Comment: Yes it is. Do i need to remove the Ctrl+Z entry from there?
I actually have multiple CWnd objects that may receive Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+V but I have no way to receive these messages in my respective CWnd's handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)&0x80)
{   if ((nChar==_T('z'))||(nChar==_T('Z')))
    {   // indicate activity
        Beep(800, 50);
    }
}
```

Additional Information:

From MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

The function `GetKeyState` retrieves the status of the specified virtual key. The status specifies whether the key is up, down, or toggled (on, off—alternating each time the key is pressed).

The key to check is the control-key, ie: VK_CONTROL. You can also refer to `GetAsyncKeyState` for more supported key name macro.

The operation (&0x80) is checking for the single high-order bit (MSB) of SHORT (8-bits)

Return value: SHORT

If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.

If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much! Could you explain a little about the check along with the     GetKeyState() call?

Answer (score 0):

When Ctrl+Z is in the accelerator list (as you wrote in a comment), than you don't Need to handle the control sequence. You will receive a WM_COMMAND message with the value, that is defined in the accelerator list.

Accelerators make it much easier and more flexible to handle the keystrokes. If a key sequence is in the accelerator list the message is translated in PreTranslateMessage and the WM_COMMAND message is send to the mainframe. Than the command handlers will do the rest. The keystroke will never arrive in the control.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on Accelerators. I haven't exactly worked on the accelerator table or know how the app uses it. My requirement is an MDI app with a frame containing many child CWnd objects. And I want to receive the ctrl+Z event for every CWnd object depending upon which is in focus at the time the keys were pressed.

Comment: Either use your own Accelerator for each control. (extend PreTranslateMessage), or never use it in the views accelerator...